# char array[] weird output

Tags: c++, arrays, char, output

```
char a[] = {'k','l','m'};
cout << a << endl;

int b[] = {1,2,3};
cout << b << endl;
```

I run the above C++ code and here's the output:

```
klm
0x22fe00
```

I observe that char is the only primary type that has this behavior. Why this is happening? Are there any specialities of the char type?

Comment: ...I'd say you're lucky the compiler _just_ prints `klm` in this case, as `a[]` is not null-terminated.

Comment: I thought the compiler puts automatically null after the end of the array.

Comment: It does if you use the string syntax: `char a[] = "klm";`. I'm pretty sure it doesn't when you use the array syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The name of an array often evaluates to the address of its first element. The standard output stream interprets character pointers as strings, and prints the data as a string. For integers, there is no such interpretation so you see the actual pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

The `char[]` is essentially how C and C++ treat strings of characters. The `operator<<` has been overloaded for the `char[]` to print out the values of the `char` array. On the other hand, arrays are essentially treated as constant pointers to their base element:

```
const int* p = &b[0];
```

Therefore, when you do `cout << b << endl`, you're actually printing out the base address of the array. That's why you get the hex number.

Comment: Actually it's overloaded for `char*`, but, close enough.